# How to set folder permission?

Tags: java, android

i am writing an android program that requires to create a folder using FTP. Folder is creating but without writing permission.

Here is code for creating folder.

```
mFTPClient.makeDirectory(dir_path);
```

I want to set write permission (CHMOD 777) on that folder.

Can anybody suggest how it can be done?

Comment: yes the server is linux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using the ftpclient. You may have to write a script/batch file to change the permission of the created directory. And do it like this:

1. Create a directory using ftpClient
2. Call a script to change the permission of that directory
3. Write something to that directory.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please use for ubntus
chmod -R 0777 module_installation/